# Sending an, intercepted and modified, submit re-loads the (wrong) page

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, greasemonkey, prototype

I use a Greasemonkey script in Firefox to intercept a submit process in order to modify a certain post variable. I save the old submit routine to call it later and overwrite `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit` with my interception (modification) function.

The problem I am currently facing is that something drops the post variable `post=Submit` and calling the (old) submit function after the modification takes me back to the current page.

```
var intercept_complete = false;

window.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    interceptor(e);
}, true);

function interceptor_setup() {
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.real_submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = interceptor;
}

function interceptor(e) {
    var frm = e ? e.target : this;
    if (!interceptor_onsubmit(frm)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!intercept_complete) {
        ModifyAndPost(frm);
        return false;
    } else {
        HTMLFormElement.prototype.real_submit.apply(frm);
        return true;
    }
}

function interceptor_onsubmit(f) {
    return !f.onsubmit || f.onsubmit();
}

function ModifyAndPost(f) {
    var attrs = new Array('name', 'type', 'value');

    for (var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++) {
        for (var a = 0; a < attrs.length; a++) {
            if (attrs[a] == 'name') {
                if (f.elements[i][attrs[a]] == "message") {
                    var current_message = f.elements[i][attrs[a + 2]];
                    if (current_message.indexOf("hello") != -1) {
                        var do_replace = confirm("Detected hello, would you like to replace that with bye?");
                        if (do_replace) {
                            f.elements[i][attrs[a + 2]] = current_message.replace("hello", "bye");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    PerformSubmit(f);
}

function PerformSubmit(f) {
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.real_submit.apply(f);
}

interceptor_setup();
```

Basically the script works and modifies the post variables successfully but when calling `HTMLFormElement.prototype.real_submit.apply(f);` to submit the modified form the request is missing the `Post=Submit` variable and the submit fails.

I tried removing `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` and then it worked sometimes, but still dropped that post variable once in a while.

Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction on this one. ;)